# Code to search in SQL for a value and if present execute a code

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I previously had a code in VB.NET that searched for a value in the DB and provided me with a result. This was the code:

```
    Class UserData
    Dim theResults = New List(Of UserData)
    Property Name As String
    Property LastName As String

End Class

Function GetData(ByVal clientNo As Integer) As List(Of UserData)


    Dim theResults = New List(Of UserData)
    Dim connStr = "serverstring"


    Using conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)

        Dim sql = "SELECT [Name], [PaternalLastName], [MaternalLastName] FROM [SocioInfo] Where ([SocioNum] = @SocioNum)"
        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocioNum", CStr(txtInput.Text))



        conn.Open()

        Dim rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

        While rdr.Read
            theResults.Add(New UserData With {
                           .Name = rdr.GetString(0),
                           .LastName = rdr.GetString(1),
                           .Maternal = rdr.GetString(2)
})

        End While

        conn.Close()

    End Using

    Return theResults

End Function

 Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click


    Dim clientNo As Integer = 0
    Dim myResults = GetData(clientNo)

    If Integer.TryParse(txtInput.Text, clientNo) Then
        If myResults.Count = 1 Then
          Execute Code
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("NAH")

        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("NAH")
    End If


End Sub
```

Now I tried to convert this code to C# but failed miserably. I used some converters I found online and it threw exceptions so I tried doing it by hand but I don't know the codes or correct way to do it since I am still learning my ropes in C#. If anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated :)

C# Code:

```
{
 theResults = new List<UserData>();
public string Nombre { get; set; }
public string Apellido { get; set; }
public string ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }


}


    public List<UserData> GetData(int clientNo)
    {


        dynamic theResults = new List<UserData>();
        dynamic connStr = "Data Source=lsf-corapbk-01;Initial Catalog=Custmast_CO;Integrated Security=Yes";


        using (conn == new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {

            dynamic sql = "SELECT [Name], [PaternalLastName], [MaternalLastName] FROM [SocioInfo] Where ([SocioNum] = @SocioNum)";
            dynamic sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocioNum", Convert.ToString(txtInput.Text));



            conn.Open();

            dynamic rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader;

            while (rdr.Read)
            {
                theResults.Add(new UserData
                {
                    Nombre = rdr.GetString(0),
                    Apellido = rdr.GetString(1),
                    ApellidoMaterno = rdr.GetString(2)
                });

            }

            conn.Close();

        }

        return theResults;

    }
```

Most of the exceptions are in the UserData area.

Comment: What C# code do you have, and what parts of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: Online Converters are not going to do as good a job as hand-written conversion.  Also, there are idioms between VB/C#...  If you convert yourself, you'll learn C# and those idioms.

Comment: Post the C# code and what exception(s) you're getting instead of the VB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public List<UserData> GetData(int clientNo)
    {
        var theResults = new List<UserData>();
        var connStr = "serverstring";

        using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Name], [PaternalLastName], [MaternalLastName] FROM [SocioInfo] Where ([SocioNum] = @SocioNum)",cnn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocioNum", txtInput.Text);
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            theResults.Add(new UserData
                                {
                                    Name = rdr.GetString(0),
                                    LastName = rdr.GetString(1),
                                    Maternal = rdr.GetString(2)
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return theResults;
    }

 public class UserData
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Maternal { get; set; }
        }
```

The button click would be...

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int clientNo = 0;
    var myResults = GetData(clientNo);
    if (int.TryParse(txtInput.Text, clientNo))
    {
        if ((myResults.Count == 1))
        {
            //Execute Code
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NAH");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NAH");
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about coding the UserData list? It's where most exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: Alright I gave your code a go but its giving me the following error: 
The type or namespace name 'UserData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @LordRelix, I will format it now - but, that should be it for the reader.  I take it you're ok with the btnSearch part?

Comment: Yeah I had the search button nailed down, thanks for that still. Will check the code and see if it works as it should, hope it does. Thanks a million Christian.

Comment: @LordRelix, post here if it worked or if anything needs changing

Comment: Its throwing me an exception (Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.). I am pretty sure I have information :P! I am searching by a specific account number and it should be grabbing the data but it isn't. Error is  in 'theResults.Add(new UserData' area. I checked a bit and verified data types but still no go.

Comment: I think it has to do with opening the reader to actually read but I still haven't gotten it working.

Comment: Added  while (rdr.Read())
                        { and it isn't throwing an exception.

Comment: @LordRelix, updated the code.  You added the connection string back in, right?